# telegrambot не отвечает. webhook на хероку

Tags: python, telegram-bot, flask, heroku

Пытаюсь настроить вебхук бота телеграмм на хероку. Пользуюсь: [pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI)
Вот мой код:

```
import os
import telebot
from flask import Flask, request

token = os.environ['TELEGRAM_TOKEN']
    
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

server = Flask(__name__)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Hello, ' + message.from_user.first_name)

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['text'])
def echo_message(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)

@server.route("/bot", methods=['POST'])
def getMessage():
    bot.process_new_updates([telebot.types.Update.de_json(request.stream.read().decode("utf-8"))])
    return "!", 200

@server.route("/")
def webhook():
    bot.remove_webhook()
    bot.set_webhook(url="https://somename.herokuapp.com/bot") #пробывал и https://somename.herokuapp.com
    return "!", 200

server.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000)))
server = Flask(__name__)
```

В логах хероку `* Running on http://0.0.0.0:16845/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)` но при этом бот не отвечает.
Мой файл procfile: `web: python bot.py`

Answer (score 0):

```
port=os.environ.get('PORT', 5000)
```

Тут динамическая типизация сыграла с вами злую шутку. Переменные окружения всегда строки, так что надо сделать преобразование.

```
port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000)
```

Comment: Спасибо за отклик, но к сожалению, это не помогло.

Comment: Не подскажите, ссылка '(url="https://git.heroku.com/myappname.git")' в правильном формате?

Comment: Мне кажется тоже нет ‎https://appname.herokuapp.com вот такая должна быть

Comment: Дополнил, не могли бы Вы взгянуть еще раз?

Comment: Больше ничего странного не вижу, я просто пользуюсь другой либой (py-telegram-bot) поэтому сказать что код точно правильный не могу